# How to lock a record while updating its value to have consistency for the value on NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, locking, netsuite, suitescript2.0

There is a Sales Order having many Purchase Orders, and the Sales Order has an item which sums up all the shipping cost in each PO.

I develop 2 functions as follows to calculate all the shipping cost in each PO:

```
function calcuTotalShippingCostByAllPOs(.....) {
        ......
    // var created_pos is an array which records all the unique PO id in SO
    for (i = 0; i < created_pos.length; i++) {
        var po_amountValue = po_record.getSublistValue({
             sublistId: 'item',
             fieldId: 'amount',
             line: ship_line
        });
        total_shipping += parseFloat(po_amountValue);
    }
    so_record.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: "item",
        fieldId: "amount",
        line: so_ship_line,
        // ignoreFieldChange: false,
        value: total_shipping
    });
}

function calcuTotalShippingCostByCurrentPO(.....) {
        ......
    switch (context.type) {
        case context.UserEventType.CREATE:
            var difference = new_po_ship_cost;
            break;
        case context.UserEventType.DELETE:
            var difference = -old_po_ship_cost;
            break;
        default:
            var difference = new_po_ship_cost - old_po_ship_cost;
            break;
        }

     // Get the old GST-Shipping cost on SO
         var old_so_ship_cost = so_record.getSublistValue({
         sublistId: 'item',
         fieldId: 'custcol_po_actual_cost',
         line: so_ship_line
     });

     // if PO UNIT COST on ship line is a finite number
     if (isNumber(old_so_ship_cost)) {
         var new_so_ship_cost = old_so_ship_cost + difference;
     } else {
         var new_so_ship_cost = difference;
     }

     so_record.setSublistValue({
         sublistId: "item",
         fieldId: "amount",
         line: so_ship_line,
         // ignoreFieldChange: false,
         value: total_shipping
     });
}
```

But if someone updates the shipping cost in a specific PO during the calculation, then the total shipping cost may be not correct.

Is it possible to lock the POs while executing the function to sum up all shipping cost?

For example, if there are 100000 POs in a SO, during the calculation of total shipping cost, if someone modify one of the shipping cost in a PO, then the total cost may be not be correct if the cost has been added in the total shipping cost.

How to prevent data inconsistency from happening on NetSuite.

Comment: So you want to update CostA while CostB and CostC are locked ? what about CostA, is it locked too ?

Comment: If one user is opening a record and updating the CostA, before the user submit the record, the hereafter users who open the record can not update the CostA.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want to do, please update your question to be more clear and add the full code (your code gets costA and then, without using that costA, it saves a newPORecord).

Comment: Hi Assem, I improved the description.

Comment: Perfect, now it is clear : I just have some questions : what is 5 minutes after the calculation, one of the POs changes, there will be inconsistency in this case too ? Or do you have some mechanism that will detect the modification of a PO and will trigger the recalculation of the SO ?

Comment: We have no more than 10 POs in a SO usually, the calculation function takes about no more than 5 seconds after the SO is submitted. But each PO may have more than 500 items. So we wonder if there is a mechanism to lock a record(PO) until another record(SO) finish its saving to make the field value consistent.

Comment: There are 2 functions to calculate the sum of shipping cost. One function will sum up all the shipping costs in each PO while there is no total shipping cost in the SO, and it will also create the shipping line with the sum on the SO. The other function just calculate the difference between the old and new shipping costs of a PO and then it will add the difference to the total shipping cost on the SO.

Comment: If there is a shipping line in the SO, then the first function execute, otherwise the second function execute to quickly update the total shipping cost. However both functions execute no more than 10 seconds while there are just 500 items belong to a SO in our case. But for date consistence, if there is a mechanism to lock a record on NetSuite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to lock the POs records you can do that using the [Lock Record](https://4769383-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n2743672.html) workflow action : if you apply that action on the BeforeLoad of a record, it will prevent its edition.

So one way to do this : you add a new checkbox Custom Body field (example: locked for calculation) : in your script, before starting the calculation, you update all the POs so that custom field is TRUE. After calculation, you reset it to FALSE.

You create a Transaction workflow with one non finishing state, and you add the Lock action with a condition : locked for calculation = TRUE.

Theoretically, this will solve your problem BUT be careful of the used Governance in your script: because you will be Updating Twice a number of POs : if it is not more than 10, it must be ok, but keep that in mind.

Good luck :)

Comment: That's a good idea, we retrieve the number from PO to add to SO, then update the cost in a PO if someone need to modify it. But why a number of POs will be updated twice?

Comment: My suggestion (it is just a suggestion) was to flag the POs before starting the calculation, to activate the Lock, ( that is the first update), then to remove the flag after the calculation, to unlock the POs (that is the second update). Now like I said, this is just a suggestion on how to use the Lock action to achieve your goal, and you can do it differently: anyway what you need is the lock workflow action.

Comment: So did I help ?

Comment: Good idea! I may need to measure how long the workflow will take. Do you have any suggestion to measure the item for workflow? I used to use log.debug and console to measure the running time of the script, but for workflow, I don't have idea now.

Comment: When you create a workflow you can activate the Log and History option : then under the System or Workflow subtab (of the record on which the workflow is applied) you can see the start and end time. Though, in your case, if the workflow is used only to lock the POs, it won't affects your script execution : because the workflow itself will run only when someone try to open a PO.